# c++ Boost serialize, error when compiling derived class

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

i'm getting a very strange error when compiling this piece of code:

```
#ifndef packetint_h
#define packetint_h
#include "../packet.h"


class packetInt: public packet{
public:
    packetInt(int pLength);
    ~packetInt();
    double distance(packet* destPacket);
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>  void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned version) {

        ar << boost::serialization::base_object<const packet>( *this);
        for(int i = 0; i<getLength(); i++)
            ar << ((int*)data)[i];
    }
    template<typename Archive>  void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned version) {
        std::cout<<"test"<<std::endl;
        ar >> boost::serialization::base_object<packet>(* this);
        data = new int[getLength()];
        for(int i = 0; i<getLength(); i++)
            ar >> ((int*)data)[i];
    }
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
};

class packetIntGenome: public packetGenome{
public:
    packetIntGenome(int pLength);
    ~packetIntGenome();
};
#endif
```

when compiling

```
C:\Users\griever\Progetti\Daana\trunk\dependencies\boost\boost/serialization/access.hpp(93): error C2662: 'void packetInt::save<Archive>(Archive &,const unsigned int)': impossibile convertire il puntatore 'this' da 'const packetInt' a 'packetInt &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive
1>          ]
1>          La conversione comporta la perdita dei qualificatori
```

i'm not sure why but removing

```
 BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
```

fix the compiling error ( but the code will not work )

sorry for my bad english, i'm italian :D

EDIT:

crawling deeper i have found the problem, still no solution btw

```
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER() 
template<typename Archive>                                          
    void serialize(Archive &ar,const unsigned int file_version){                                                              
        boost::serialization::split_member(ar, *this, file_version); <--- this is not working
    }
```

Comment: The save template method should be constant. Try to add `const` to the end of the save method declaration, i.e. `template<typename Archive>  void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned version) const {`

Comment: Please a) compile with LC_ALL=C, b) 'this is not working' is not a valid error message, be more verbose.

Comment: @megabyte1024 thanks for the answer! tried but still the same error

Comment: @kfunk thanks for the answer you too! sorry but where i have to put "LC_ALL=C"? for the b) point: the "this is not working" line causes the error at compiling time pasted few lines above, commenting it allow me to compile without errors

Comment: woa woa woa hold on, my mistake! with @megabyte1024 's changes the error has changed! now it complains about error C2662: 'packet::getLength': impossibile convertire il puntatore 'this' da 'const packetInt' a 'packet &'

Comment: @user2064399: see for example: http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/01/how-to-change-your-default-locale-on.html -- localized compiler error messages are not really useful on SO.

Comment: @kfunk you are right! this is a good point XD i'll reinstall all the package with english language by default, btw the translated error is: 
cannot convert the pointer 'this' from 'const packetInt' to 'packetInt &'

Comment: @user2064399, declare the packet::getLength method as constant as well.

Comment: @megabyte1024 thank you very much!!! now everything works pretty well :D how do i tag a question as closed?

Comment: @user2064399, I posted an answer basing on the comments. You can mark it as "Accepted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on the comments. To fix the problem you have to declare the `save` method as constant.

```
template<typename Archive> void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned version) const {
  // ...
}
```

Accordingly, all methods which are used inside of the `save` method should be constant as well.